# Is Array.Clear() in C# suitable for zeroing sensitive byte arrays?

Tags: encryption, .net

Is it worth calling [Array.Clear()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clear?view=net-5.0) to clear sensitive byte arrays such as those containing encryption keys? It's not clear whether this is worth doing since the language has a garbage collector.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320345/clearing-out-a-c-sharp-byte-array-with-sensitive-data

Comment: If you want to do this, you might want to use [`IList.Clear()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.system-collections-ilist-clear?view=net-5.0#System_Array_System_Collections_IList_Clear) instead of `Array.Clear(Array,int,int)` as the latter is a static function that requires you to specify the range of elements to clear (though `Array.Clear(myArr,0,myArr.Length)` would work).

Answer (score 2):

**No, using [Array.Clear()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clear?view=net-5.0) is not safe for clearing secret data.**

All it does, as per the above documentation, is to set the elements to the default value. It is stated nowhere, that this is a cryptographically safe operation. The code behind it could just update the array's links to new default items.

And even then, the data would stay in memory at least until garbage collection, presumably longer.

You might want to look into the [Security in .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/) documentation.

Comment: A byte array doesn't contain "links" to items.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely correct, in that sensitive information should be cleared out of memory, but I would recommend against implementing anything that close to the cryptographic primitives.  I always recommend using a well vetted library to implement any cryptography.
There is a list of decent libraries
in this other SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180365/recommended-net-encryption-library), with BouncyCastle being the reference implementation.  One of these libraries should take handle the clearing of memory for you.  Cryptography is one of the easiest things to screw up, so it's best practice to go with a out-of-the-box solution, which handles the easy to screw up parts for you.